# how to select the first punch of an associate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

how to select only the first punch of that particular day
4th column represents the inpunchs of that day the code I used is

```
select personfullname,personnum,eventdate,min(STARTDTM)

 from VP_TIMESHEETITMV42

where eventdate ='2019-12-18 00:00:00.000' 
and EMPLOYEEID = '283401'

group by personfullname, personnum, eventdate, startdtm,PAYCODENAME,DATASOURCEID
```

[image]

Comment: "select personfullname,personnum,eventdate,min(STARTDTM)" should work. does not it? It should show only one row which consists minimum value

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one row, then use `top (1)`:

```
select top (1) ts.*
from VP_TIMESHEETITMV42 ts
where ts.eventdate = '2019-12-18' and
      ts.EMPLOYEEID = 283401
order by ts.stardtm;
```

I am assuming that `employeeid` is a number.  If so, single quotes should not be used for the comparison value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per day and employee with their first punch, you can filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from VP_TIMESHEETITMV42 t
where t.startdtm = (
    select min(t1.startdtm)
    from VP_TIMESHEETITMV42 t1
    where t1.eventdate = t.eventdate and t1.employee_id = t.employee_id
)
```

You can then add more conditions in the `where` clause to filter on a specific employee and/or a specific day.

Comment: There can be more than one lines with the same startdtm minimum value

Comment: @DmitryReutov: for the same employee (and the same day)?

Comment: I dont see in your code any filter about employer except the subquery which does not reflects the main query, and even if so - it doesnt matter - if you work with data - you should keep in mind all the cases